# SessionState Exception thrown by ASP.NET MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, session-state

Is there any reason why Session related code throws a SessionState exception while other parts of a site does not?  Everything worked previously, but it seems a change has taken place somewhere.  I'm not sure which setting in IIS or elsewhere would resolve it.

Here is the error:

*System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \ section in the application configuration. at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Session() at MRG.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ....\MRG.master.cs:line 45*

Here is MRG.master.cs:line 45:

```
if (Session["myID"] != null)

   ...
```

Here is the Global.asax session entry that worked with no errors:

```
   void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Identity visitor = new Identity("abcde");
        Session["myID"] = visitor;
    }
```

Also, here is the web.config entry that also worked before on another site:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
```

Comment: "Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive". Does your config file or page contain this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true either in a configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334147/session-state-can-only-be-used-when-enablesessionstate-is-set-to-true-either-in)