# keeping data for multiple steps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I have 3 steps, each step is its on view. On step 1 I ask for the start date/time(they can pick timezone and time) and store it as UTC, on step 3 I want to show the date/time based on the timezone they selected, without knowing which timezone they selected (don't store it, as users see it based on the computer timezone).

I want to know the best way to do this.  I was thinking storing the tempdata, and then re-storing it. Though it doesn't seem like a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the model(s) you use for steps 2 and 3 have a `Timezone` property, you could store the value in a hidden field and have it posted back to you, like this:

```
Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Timezone);
```

Alternatives would be putting the value in a cookie (and perhaps then using a [CookieValueProvider](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/03/07/aspnet-mvc-working-smart-with-cookies-custom-valueprovider/) to get it back) or putting it in session, although the last option [isn't really how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181629/why-session-is-a-disaster-in-asp-net-mvc-application) MVC is 'meant' to be used.

Comment: I like the idea of making a Timezone property for the model for step 2 and the model for step 3. Wouldn't be much different then passing a TempData to another TempData, but its a bit cleaner

Comment: Yeah, `Timezone` sounds like a natural part of your model, so it makes sense to me to treat it as such rather than taking the steps necessary to put something in TempData for two Post-Redirect-Gets.