# Session value is null app code cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have used the below code in app code `session.cs` file. It has been loaded initially in httpmodule.cs, whenever every page hit in browser. I found the `httpcontext.current.session` value is `null`.

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Count > 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["ecm"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["ecmSecure"].Expires = DateTime.Now;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

web.config session settings :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" 
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
              sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" 
              cookieless="false" 
              timeout="5" />
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705802/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-in-mvc-3-appplication) will probably be helpful

Comment: Sorry jonesy. It isn't help full

Comment: What exactly means "loaded initially" ? Is that webforms or MVC asp.net app ? How session is declared in web.config ?

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="5" />
Intially loaded the httpmodule.cs then we access the session there.

Comment: So initially really means in BeginRequest of HttpModule ?

Comment: From my experiences (I haven't been able to validate it, so just a comment) but the global Session variable doesn't become initialized until after the base Controller (custom or otherwise) has completed it's initialization. For this reason you can't reference Session from before this point, otherwise you'll get a null. Even calling it during a custom Controller constructor will result in null. Once the base Controller is initialized it seems to work fine, even during a constructor for the inherited controller.

Comment: What if you change your web.config to simple `<sessionState mode="InProc" />` ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be to wrap it in a property and access it like a string:-

```
string SessionVariable
{
   get{
      return Session("SessionVariable") ?? String.Empty;
   }
   set{
      Session("SessionVariable") = value;
   }
}
```

then use like:-

```
if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( SessionVariable) )
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: sorry rahul. I didn't use web service. I use seesion.cs file in app code directory.

Comment: And what about IRequiresSessionState ??

Comment: this is not supported...any way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends with responses. I found the answer. The session value is generated http module. only the end request is called after access the session value. The below code i used.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(context_EndRequest);
    context.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(SessionClear);
}

public void SessionClear(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            if (!(HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Count > 0))
            {

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```