# How do I perform an action before any view(or partial) is rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My problem is simple. I want to know if there is a method(or something) that is automatically called by default(by ASP.Net engine) before any view(or partial) is rendered. I like to intercept it to perform an action, e.g generate a random number.

I will explain my scenario in case of somebody have a better idea.

My app's views and partials renders elements with an id pattern like this: `Model_Id`. In some cases, when user brings up a modal window with a view that repeats the id of any element of the main window, my jquery selectors get confused. I've already create *custom* helpers to do that behavior, so I thought about generate random number(and store it on session) and concat it in the id, to get something like `Model_Id_1234` or `1234_Model_Id`.

If there is a better way, it will be really nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write a [custom action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) to allow you to intercept ahead of the action performing. This would then be called using the method:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // do your pre action display stuff here!!
    // if the code is added to basecontroller - 
    // also optionally defer back to base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

I'll add to the answer with further detail as literally in transit just now.

See [this post on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612%28v=vs.98%29), it covers the controller pipeline for MVC.

**[Edit]** - in response to comment, see also this SO answer: [Calling the Session before any Controller Action is run in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263936/calling-the-session-before-any-controller-action-is-run-in-mvc/3263961#3263961). In effect, in this example, we don't create an actionfilter, we only override the `OnActionExecuting` inside the base controller.

Comment: But I will have to add that filter on each controller I want that behavior, right? There is a way to do it automatically?

Comment: well, you can add a basecontroller to make this happen for you. i have asnwered a similar question before, related to this type of use. let me reference it for you and add to answer..

Comment: I was searching for other things to test this solution, and I found another answer of you that helped me. So you helped me with 3 answers in one haha. Thank you, it worked. Keep this great job!!

Comment: lol, luv when you get the old `3 for the price of one... ` scenario. glad you're up and running..